# Reflections and ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How can I use byte-buddy generated classes with "org.reflections"?

Example:

```
    Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .name("de.testing.SomeClass")
            .method(ElementMatchers.named("toString"))
            .intercept(FixedValue.value("Hello World!"))
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader(),ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
            .getLoaded();
```

Now I want to use org.reflections to find all subtypes of Object inside a specific Package:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("de.testing");
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> objs = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    for (Class clazz : objs ) {
        log.info("{}",clazz.getName());
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont get your question. What is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: The problem is that Reflections doesn't pick up the generated java classes from byte buddy.

Comment: Probably because byte body is creating things "in memory"; whereas that *other* utility code maybe queries the class path and only searches within existing class files it finds there?

Comment: Any idea on how to make them work together?

Comment: Rest assured: if I had an idea that would merit an answer; I would have written down that answer. Because that is what I do here: writing answer (to gain reputation ;-) ... but the real thing here is probably: why do you want to do that; what is the underlying problem you try to resolve here?

Comment: I've a code base which looks up specific Classes  with "reflections" based on location and annotations. I want to define these Classes at runtime

Comment: Well, if it is "all your code"; why doesn't **your** code remember the classes it crated itself; and "joins" that information with the information collected by that other call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, reflections scans the class path by querying class loaders for its resources. This does normally only work for standard class loaders whereas Byte Buddy creates classes in memory where they are not found using resource scanning.

You can work around this by storing Byte Buddy's classes in a jar file and loading this jar file manually using a `URLClassLoader`. Byte Buddy allows you to create a jar by `.make().toJar( ... )`. You can then provide this class loader to reflections which by default only scans the system class loader.

All this does however seem like quite a complex solution to a problem that could be easily solved by registering your types somewhere explicitly.

Comment: Thx for the clarification. Is there a way to query all ByteBuddy created classes in memory?

Comment: No, you would need to remember them. Referencing them would not be a good idea as this makes them impossible to garbage collect.